# Django FileField throws attribute error when storing ContentFile

Tags: python, django

I create a ContentFile instance from a string passed to it and try to save it to the model like this:

```
def generate_file_path(instance, filename):
    path = f"{instance.name}/{instance.field}_{filename}"
    return path

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    field = CharField(max_length=100)
    upload = models.FileField(
        _("Skan"),
        storage=settings.FILE_STORAGE,
        upload_to=generate_file_path
    )

file = ContentFile('sample content', name='file.txt')
instance = SampleModel(upload=file, name='name', field='field_info')
instance.save()
```

But when saving it throws

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'generate_filename'`

which is weird, because FileField should handle ContentFile instance. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `ContentFile` is missing the `generate_filename` attribute that the `upload_to` function defined in `SewageCompanyConsts` is expecting..

You can assign the `filename` to the `ContentFile` instance explicitly before assigning it to the `FileField`:

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(
        _("Skan"),
        storage=settings.FILE_STORAGE,
        upload_to=SewageCompanyConsts.generate_file_path
    )

file = ContentFile('sample content')
file.name = 'file.txt'
instance = SampleModel(upload=file)
instance.save()
```

Comment: It still gives the same error. Strangely when I try to save `File` instance to the FileField like this: `file = open('files/umowa.html', 'r')` `file.name='name.txt'` `instance = SampleModel(upload=File(file))` it still gives me the same error

Comment: Check the implementation of the generate_file_path function in the SewageCompanyConsts class and make sure it returns a valid string representing the path where you want to store the uploaded file!
(Can you edit your post and paste the code there?)

Comment: I have updated the code, `generate_file_path` returns valid string

Comment: I meant, can you share the code of the SewageCompanyConsts class?

Comment: That's the code, generate_file_path is a static method in the SewageCompanyConsts class, I only use this function from the class

Comment: Sorry, I just refreshed the page, can you `add print(type(instance))` in the beginning of the generate_file_path function? Just to make sure that the instance is an instance of SampleModel and tell me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251574/discussion-between-nova-and-wiktorks).